# Create my own navigation/routing system

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, navigation

I'm studding AI course and I need to create a routing or navigation program.

I live in Barcelona and first at all I need Barcelona's street network data. I have found it here https://mapzen.com/metro-extracts/ (but I don't know it this data is good enough to use it in a navigation system).

Here, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing, I have found more information about routing but I'm terrible lost.

Where do you recommend me to start with this?

I have to implement my own version of A* algorithm. I only need data, but reading the previous page I see that Openstreet data has information about speed, highway type, etc.

I'm sorry, but I'm lost and I don't know where to start with.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the data structure issue and just do the implementation? If so, I'd re-use the framework provided by spatialite or postgis, which already support Dijkstra and A*. Then you can just plug in your own variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but my reading of your current problem could be solved - and I mean this in good spirits - by doing the pgRouting workshop:

http://pgrouting.org/documentation.html -- see the workshop and tutorials part.

The value here is you'll get a good sense of what you can do with your MapZen extract, how to use OSM2PGRouting, how to build the network, how to use the algorithms, how the routing data really works, and then plot a course for how you want to use the data.

I recently went through the workshop, which at one point made ZERO sense to me. But after coming back to it and taking a few side-trips of my own with the individual results of the workshop, I have a MUCH better understanding of what can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list:

1. Create a simple in-memory graph with nodes and edges.
2. Apply A* to it (there are many examples on the web)
3. Then look into the OSM data structure and build a simple parser (or reuse existing) to fill your in-memory graph
4. then run A* on it via nodeIDs or lat/lon for start and end location
5. create the address search which returns a nodeID or lat/lon from the input
6. make a visualization

Sounds crazy complex? It is :)

Or look into existing tools which will help you with some of these points, like the tools found in your routing link.

BTW: I can recommend [GraphHopper](https://graphhopper.com/maps/) as I'm the author ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to implement your own, then read here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

That way you learn the most.

But if you start from scratch and want to implement ALL steps on your own, then it is a major task you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Streets data are the most important part of your project. You have to get vector data with few requirements:

- it must be a complete network, without gaps and isolated streets
- each street beetween two nodes should be a single object, it should start and end in particular node, you can even split streets to straight lines (each single straight line is single object)

I think there is no big problem to get a shapefile with streets in major european cities. 
Try this datasets: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/spain.html
I've got similar ds for whole Poland and it's quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the OSM data is good for street routing even if it doesn't have all the street names, the road edges are pretty good.
There are solutions out there that do a pretty good job of doing what you are looking for without needing to fully implement.
A good starting point is OpenStreetMap Routing Project at http://project-osrm.org/

But as a student I can strongly recommend GraphHopper - spend some time going through this and the linked resources. Look also at contraction hierarchies, distance matrices and optimisation algorithms such as LKH (Keld Helsgaun)